# What is this 'noise' in my Oracle database traffic?

Tags: oracle, tcp, wireshark

I have a requirement to intercept data coming from an application to an Oracle database. I've investigated a proof of concept, where I have a Spring Boot application querying from, and writing some data to, the DB, and then capturing the TCP traffic using RawCap.

The intention is to be able to reconstruct the sequence of queries from the TCP traffic log, and to be able to reason over how the database has changed given these queries. I'm aware this sounds like an X/Y problem, but I've validated that this is process is necessary - that this data *must* be captured, and that there is no other way to capture it. The reason it's necessary is that I want to selectively capture traffic: given two applications, A and B, connecting to the database, I only want to understand how A has influenced the database, and I do not necessarily have access to the source code of A to be able to log changes there.

When I look at the TCP traffic in Wireshark, I see a lot of extraneous characters in the logs.

For instance, given a `CommandLineRunner` in my application with the following implementation:

```
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("\n4.findByEmailReturnStream(@Param(\"email\") String email)...");
        try (Stream<Customer> stream = customerRepository.findByEmailReturnStream("333@yahoo.com")) {
            stream.forEach(System.out::println);
        }
    }
```

I see the line below in the Wireshark capture, corresponding to this query.

```
**ÿÿÿ****************************select customer0_.id as id1_0_, customer0_.created_date as created_date2_0_, customer0_.email as email3_0_, customer0_.name as name4_0_ from customer customer0_ where customer0_.email=:1 ************€*********4*******i****
333@yahoo.com
```

Can anyone explain these asterisks and other unusual characters? Is there a canonical way for me to 'clean' this traffic so I can extract only the queries?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They are most likely protocol control characters of some kind. Not sure there would be a good way to clean those out, but others might have more experience with that. That said, is there a reason that database auditing would not work for what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @pmdba . I don't believe auditing will work because, as far as I'm aware, the database cannot know which applications that have connected to it are applications 'of interest', and should therefore have the traffic monitored. As I said, given applications A and B, I only want to capture traffic between A and the DB, not B. In reality, there are ~30 applications, and I want to capture traffic between 20 of them and the DB. Can auditing be this selective over connections?

Comment: Do all of the applications use the same userid to connect to the database? Are they actually running on the same app server and using the same connection pool? Just trying to understand how dense the distinct application traffic is...

Comment: Are you using any JDBC driver ? If any, add the corresponding tag to your question to get more attention to your question. Upvoting for now.

Comment: @EugèneAdell I can't rely on the use of a JDBC driver, some of the applications I need to get information from are not Java applications.

Comment: @pmdba some applications have their own user ID, but many use a shared 'superuser' with permissions to basically do anything. Similar story with application servers, some apps run on dedicated infrastructure, others share app servers.